# Reply to reviews using Google my business

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api

I want to publish review replies on google my business page.

Code:

```
import google.auth.transport.requests

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

# Load credentials from JSON file
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '///credentials.json')
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage"])

DISCOVERY_DOC = "https://developers.google.com/static/my-business/samples/mybusiness_google_rest_v4p9.json"


# Build the Google My Business API service
service = build('mybusiness', 'v4', credentials=scoped_credentials, discoveryServiceUrl = DISCOVERY_DOC)

# Define the business account ID and review ID
account_id = '*******'
review_id = '*******'
location_id = *****

# Define the reply text
reply_text = 'Hi! Thank you so much for your positive feedback!'

# Send the review reply
request = service.accounts().locations().reviews().updateReply(
    name=f'accounts/{account_id}/locations/{location_id}/reviews/{review_id}',
    body={'comment': reply_text}
)
response = request.execute()

# Print the response
print(response)
```

Below are the service account credentials
**credentials.json**

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "*******",
  "private_key_id": "####****######",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----*****-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "****@**.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "#############",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "##########.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

Please help us understand why this error. I don't see anything wrong, I followed the documentation correctly.
I have checked replacing the '**mybusinessbusinessinformation**' and '**v1**' with '**mybusiness**' and '**v4**' respectively, but still no success.
I have even tried sending the response using the API key but that also doesn't work.

**Update**

I missed the discovery file, now added it. But now the execute function doesn't work. If I use execute() it gives below error else works fine but no output.

Error:

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/****/locations/****/reviews/***/reply?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.". Details: "Requested entity was not found.">
```

I have tried to solve using Outh2 access token:

```
import requests
import json

access_token = "ya29.******"

def reply_to_review(account_id, review_id, reply_text, location_id):
    endpoint = 'https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{}/locations/{}/reviews/{}/reply'.format(
      account_id, location_id, review_id)
    
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
    }
    
    payload = {
        'comment': reply_text
    }
    
    try:
        response = requests.put(endpoint, headers=headers, json=payload)
        response.raise_for_status()
        print('Reply submitted successfully.')
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
        print(f'Error: {error}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'An error occurred: {str(e)}')

# Example usage:
account_id = '*****'
review_id = '*****'
reply_text = 'Hi jose! Thank you for the review'
location_id = '*******'
reply_to_review(account_id, review_id, reply_text, location_id)
```

Still getting the same error:

```
Error: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/****/locations/****/reviews/****/reply
```

Comment: In your `request`, there could be an issue with the method you are using. Based on the documentation at [Official Business Profile API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list), the method should be `accounts.locations.reviews.list` ***(`review()` has to be `reviews()` with an 's')***. You can also see that in the error you are getting the `"object has no attribute 'review'"` as apparently it doesn't really exist. Can you double check?

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 Agreed. I did the changes but still the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that service accounts can be used to access Google Reviews?

Comment: @NoCommandLine: let's say service accounts cannot be used for this purpose, then what will be the correct solution programmatically? Using OAuth 2 access token?

Comment: Yes. If service accounts can't be used, then you have to use OAuth 2 access token. The [Official Business Profile API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/updateReply) links to an OAuth 2.0 document at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @NoCommandLine: I tried that after generating Outh2 access token, but getting Error: 404 Client Error: Not Found for URL: https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/***/locations/****/reviews/***/reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I used the latter approach to solve this issue as service accounts cannot be used to work with review data. The problem was the access token.

First try to replicate the scenario in **OAuth 2.0 Playground** https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Next, make sure the user has ownership of all the locations. Check client id, client secret. Do a GET request to `https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts` you should see HTTP 200 response.

For ease of use try building a solution which can automatically refresh access token from your code.

Comment: Hi @Nagesh, did you get business api access?

Comment: Yes, please follow instructions.

Comment: thanks @Nagesh. already got the permission

Answer (score 0):

The reply endpoint requires PUT not POST.
Reference: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/updateReply