# Getting 404 not found in Google my business

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-my-business-api

Hi I'm trying to get reviews from google My business API. But after trying everything it gives me 404 not found error. I contact Google Cloud support, they said Google cloud support doesn't look after Google my business. Its a dead end asking any kind of support from Google. First they have a terrible documentation which compels you to buy the standard plan, once you buy they will raise hands saying they can't help(Shame). I'm forced to use GCP as GMB is handled by Google otherwise it will a blind choice between Azure or AWS.

Anyways check [this](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/#step3&scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbusiness.manage&postData=%7B%22comment%22%3A%20%22Hi%20Sagar%20Chaudhary!%20Thank%20you%20for%20the%20positive%20response.%20Team%20OYO%22%7D&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmybusiness.googleapis.com%2Fv4%2Faccounts&content_type=application%2Fjson&http_method=GET&useDefaultOauthCred=checked&oauthEndpointSelect=Google&oauthAuthEndpointValue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Fv2%2Fauth&oauthTokenEndpointValue=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2.googleapis.com%2Ftoken&includeCredentials=unchecked&accessTokenType=bearer&autoRefreshToken=unchecked&accessType=offline&prompt=consent&response_type=code&wrapLines=on) link to replicate my issue on Google OAuth 2.0 Playground.

[image]

Comment: The [API docs](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/list) say it's deprecated. They're probably out-of-date and it's actually been removed

Comment: Thank you @Phil, Can I use mybusinessaccountmanagement API to post review response or I need to use mybusiness API ?

Comment: @Phil: If you can help here, this is the main issue which even Google Cloud support couldn't solve:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76672126/reply-to-reviews-using-google-my-business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Correct Endpoint: `https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts`

The user should have ownership of all the locations and the access token should be generated from the same user.

Comment: Why did you not mark my answer as the correct answer then?

Comment: Check the comment from Phil, he already got this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The accounts list method that is part of the [My Business API v4](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/list) that you are trying to use was deprecated and removed.

The accounts list method that is part of the [Business Profile APIs v1](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/accountmanagement/rest/v1/accounts/list) should be used instead.